# No Device drivers were found while installing windows

Tags: windows

Here is the situation, I was trying to install Windows 10 on my PC. I have cleaned the hard disk (including the C drive which contained my Windows OS) and started installation with my bootable usb. I was getting an error called **"No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers, and then click OK."**. I tried changing usb stick to different ports but the problem still exists. I have tried the same usb stick for my laptop to check whether the Windows installation is corrupted or not, and it was working perfectly fine. After that I searched and found that by installing intel rapid storage drivers might fix the issue but I was not able to install it because my bootable usb is not visible in the browse section. It only shows C drive (which is empty), a disk drive and a boot drive (but it does not contain those files). Later, I thought of using DVD for the device drivers and tried installing but it gave an error that either files are not correct or they are not present in installation media. I can even burn Windows iso on DVD as the size of iso file is larger than my DVD. I tried

```
diskpart
list disk # But this shows only my harddrive and not my usb stick, even if I connect multiple usb stick. I have 6 different ports available but none of them worked in detecting it.
clean
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs
exit
```

I also tried installing Windows 7 but the same issue persist. In short, I am not able to install any of the Windows OS. Can anyone please help. THANK YOU!

Comment: Make and model of problem PC?

Comment: Manufacturer : Intel Corporation
Product : DH55TC
Version : AAE70932-206

Comment: Where is the Windows install media coming from _(media creation tool, DVD, etc )_? There are some legacy boards that may require [injection of drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-and-remove-drivers-to-an-offline-windows-image) into the WinPE `sources\boot.wim` _(usually index 2 is Windows Setup)_. If the motherboard's manual doesn't specify which drivers, emailing Intel tech support will likely be the fastest way to determine the solution - it's likely storage drivers.